# Use "inb" ASM with register as first arg

Tags: assembly, hardware-port

I would like to use it that way :

```
inb %cl, %al
```

But I get :

```
idt_asm.S:43: Error: operand type mismatch for `in'
```

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the instruction is not that general.

See [this reference page](http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/in.htm) for the supported argument forms.

Basically, for bytes (`inb`) there are two forms:

1. `inb imm8, al`
2. `inb dx, al`

So the destination is always `al`, and the source is either immediate or taken from `dx`.

Comment: Thank you for the reference page !
Problem solved then.